# C# TypeKind of string? is TypeKind.Class

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis, sourcegenerators

**Rephrased question:**
I have this equalitycomparer with Generic type constrained to a `class`

```
public class ReferenceEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : class
{
    public static ReferenceEqualityComparer<T> Default => new();

    public bool Equals(T? x, T? y) => ReferenceEquals(x, y);

    public int GetHashCode(T? obj) => RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj);
}
```

when a class let's say

```
public class A
{
   public string? P1{get; set;}
}
```

is consumed by a code generator

```
[Generator]
public class MyCodeGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
}
```

the NetAnalyzer says that `string?` has a TypeKind of class

but when I do this,

```
#nullable enable        
[TestMethod]
public void RefTest()
{
    string? s1 = "adsad";
    string? s3 = s1;
    Assert.IsTrue(ReferenceEqualityComparer<string?>.Default.Equals(s1, s3));
}
#nullable restore
```

it says that `string?`does not match 'class' constraint. Even though the analyzer is telling me that its a class, am I missing something here? or have I misunderstood the concept?

**Original question:** According to the description of [Nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-5.0) from Microsoft Documentation, they are classified as `structs`, but why is it that the CodeAnalyzer is telling me that the TypeKind of `string?` is a TypeKind.Class?

Here's some context, in a library I'm writing, classes are analyzed for Source Generation (C# 9 Source Generator) which is essentially using .NetAnalyzer. Each of the properties of the class will be checked whether their type is considered as a class. It turns out `string?` is considered as a Class.

Comment: strings are nullable classes anyway. `string s = null;` is perfectly valid code.

Comment: `string?` is not the same as `Nullable<string>` (and as a matter of fact, the 2nd isn't valid anyway). From the very first part of the doc you linked: "Represents a value type that can be assigned null". Strings are not a value type and do not apply here, so you're comparing apples to oranges in a way.

Comment: Might want to read more about nullable reference types, such as `String`. It think this was introduced in C# 8, but not quite sure about that.

Comment: You probably want to read into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/nullable-reference-types-specification ... But your `ReferenceEqualityComparer` does not *expect* nullable ref types as it uses `Equals(T? x, T? y) ` inside - so you need to come up with more plausible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) a specific constraint for nullable classes in C#, so from constraint standpoint in compile time `SomeRefType?` does not match `T:class`, but it will match `T:class?`.

> `where T : class` The type argument must be a reference type. This constraint applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type. **In a nullable context in C# 8.0 or later, T must be a non-nullable reference type**.

> `where T : class?` The type argument must be a reference type, either nullable or non-nullable. This constraint applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

So possibly in nullable context you will want to use the second one:

```
public class ReferenceEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : class?
```

Which will not give any warnings neither for `string?` nor for `string`.

Answer (score 1):

[`string`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-5.0) are classes and cannot be used as generic type argument for `Nullable` because of the generic constraint `where T : struct`. In your context `string?` is a [nullable reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references), which can be used to incdicate to the compiler that a reference type should not have `null` as value (variables still can have `null` as value and should be checked for `null` values in public APIs, but the compiler will warn you when you use `null` in a non-nullable context)